# Replace ";" to "&" during recording in jmeter

Tags: replace, jmeter, beanshell

I point main informations:

1. I record with HTTP Proxy server with Recording Controller
2. In url address I get for example: `https://server/stuff?Action=oneAction;Subaction=secondAction`
3. This site give me an error
4. All I have to change in adress is replace ";" with "&"
5. Site `https://server/stuff?Action=oneAction&Subaction=secondAction` works great

Is it possible to have a function, that will automatically replace ";" with "&"? I can't record without it
I found something like: https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/EscapedURLs but, it doesn't work automatically when I record it.

Is it possible to avoid a semicolon?

EDIT:
I found where the problem is: with the proxy - it gets semicolon and changes it to HEX %3b in the url, but the server doesn't recognise `https://server/stuff?Action=oneAction%3bSubaction=secondAction`and makes error. So I think the problem is with encoding of proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JMeter .jmx files are basically XML so you can do it after the recording via your favourite text editor. In the meantime there are some alternative ways of recording a JMeter test:

1. [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) proxy can export recorded traffic in form of JMeter .jmx file
2. [JMeter Chrome extension](https://docs.blazemeter.com/customer/portal/articles/1528451-chrome-extension) allows recording a JMeter test right from Chrome browser without having to set up any proxies

Comment: If only I can do that after recording... The main issue I can't record it, because JS on site gives me error, which prevents me from recording :( I'll check sites out

Answer (score 0):

No there is no such function.

But you may have an option using the "Recording" template and filling User Defined Variable with a row:

- Name : SEPARATOR
- Value : ;

[image]

Then replace value ';' by '&'

But it can be dangerous as ; may be replaced even where you don't want it to be.

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks for suggestion :) I found where the problem is: with the proxy - it gets semicolon and changes it to HEX %3b in the url, but the server doesn't recognise %3b and makes error, check again the question

Comment: What version of JMeter are you using ?

Comment: But how can I replace ";" with "&"? By BeanShell script? I'm a total noob :(